# App not running on Android 19, but runs on Android >19

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, verifyerror

I built an android app, when try to run on devices running android 19, I receive this error, I can't track any missing APIs or unimplemented methods in OS 19.

```
03-24 09:26:08.118 2668-2668/com.cac.lingo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: com.cac.lingo, PID: 2668
                                                                java.lang.VerifyError: com/cac/lingo/LoginActivity
                                                                    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is `com.cac.lingo.LoginActivity` your code?

Comment: Yes, it's my code.

Comment: You might want to consider editing your question and posting the source to it, as part of a [mcve]. Otherwise, double-check your superclass and all fields, as you would appear to be referencing something that does not exist. Also, if you are getting this crash on a particular device, try another API Level 19 device or emulator, and see if you get the problem there as well.

Comment: Yes, I receive same error on emulator having API Level 19

Comment: Have you got any solution to resolve it? if yes please let  me know

Comment: @SARATHV Yes, it was missing finger print hardware!

Comment: @AVEbrahimi how you resolved this issue? Is that about run-time permission or hardware access with new API ..? or how to resolve it?

Comment: @AVEbrahimi Can you explain, how you resolved the issue.

Comment: Devices having Android 19 does not have fingerprint hardware, so one should not check/initialize fingerprint at all.